# SafeMySQL replaces FLOAT with INT

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I need to insert a float number into my table. I use SafeMySQL so I need to use ?s in my query to put a FLOAT number. What I've tried:

```
$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(?s)", 4.123); // inserts 4
$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(?s)", floatval(4.123)); // inserts 4
$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(?s)", (string)4.123); // inserts 4

$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(?s)", '4.123'); // inserts 4.123
$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(4.123)"); // inserts 4.123
```

This happens to all other tables as well. So to insert a FLOAT using SafeMySQL I have to convert my float to a string, or insert the plain value inside the query (which looks like exactly opposite of what SafeMySQL is for). This seems absolutely ridiculous and I can't find any info on the web.

I just want to insert a FLOAT num, am I missing something? What is wrong here? xD

Thanks!

Comment: I never heard of safemysql and i recommend you to ise the standard way of **prepared statements**. 'That is atleast safe

Comment: Hi, according to your last line example  `$db -> query("INSERT INTO tablename(`certs`) VALUES(4.123)");`, the problem is in the `query` function, it takes the float and converts it to int before sending the SQL to the db, you need to read the `query` function doc to find if there is any parameter/way to avoid this.

Comment: This is [SafeMySQL source code](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php). It's not really a wrapper for prepared statements. There's no binding done in it and strings are just escaped using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. I'd advise against it and rather recommend [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo). Unless there's another wrapper of the same name, but I haven't found it.

Comment: @El_Vanja wow, thanks for sharing. Yes, that is SafeMySQL which my programmer chose for our service. I didn't know it was so outdated and practically of no much use. I just switched to prepared statements, and everything works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[@El_Vanja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4205384/el-vanja) advised not to use SafeMySQL and switch to [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo), which I did.